# Is that any faster way to deleting Excel row using openpyxl?

Tags: python, performance, openpyxl

I have a list of excel row numbers that I want to delete with 2138 length using Openpyxl. Here is the code :

```
delete_this_row = [1,2,....,2138]

for delete in delete_this_row:
    worksheet.delete_rows(delete)
```

But its too slow. It takes 45 seconds until 1 minute to finish the process.

Is that any faster way to complete the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's almost *always* a faster way to do something. Sometimes the cost is too high but not in this case, I suspect :-)

If it's just a set of contiguous rows you want to delete, you can just use:

```
worksheet.delete_rows(1, 2138)
```

Documentation [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.delete_rows), copied below for completeness:

> `delete_rows(idx, amount=1)`: Delete row or rows from `row==idx`.

Your solution is slow since, *every* time you delete a single row, it has to shift *everything* beneath that point up one row then delete the final row.

By passing in the row count, it instead does *one* shift, shifting rows `2139..max` straight up to rows `1..max-2138`, then deletes all the rows that are below `max-2138`.

This is likely to be roughly 2,138 times faster than what you have now :-)

---

If you have *arbitrary* row numbers in your array, you can still use this approach to optimise it as much as possible.

The idea here is to first turn your row list into a tuple list where each tuple has:

- the starting row; and
- the number of rows to delete from there.

Ideally, you'd also generate this in reverse order so you could just process it as is. The following snippet shows how you could do this, with the openpyxl calls being printed rather than called:

```
def reverseCombiner(rowList):
    # Don't do anything for empty list. Otherwise,
    # make a copy and sort.

    if len(rowList) == 0: return []
    sortedList = rowList[:]
    sortedList.sort()

    # Init, empty tuple, use first item for previous and
    # first in this run.

    tupleList = []
    firstItem = sortedList[0]
    prevItem = sortedList[0]

    # Process all other items in order.

    for item in sortedList[1:]:
        # If start of new run, add tuple and use new first-in-run.

        if item != prevItem + 1:
            tupleList = [(firstItem, prevItem + 1 - firstItem)] + tupleList
            firstItem = item

        # Regardless, current becomes previous for next loop.

        prevItem = item

    # Finish off the final run and return tuple list.

    tupleList = [(firstItem, prevItem + 1 - firstItem)] + tupleList
    return tupleList

# Test data, hit me with anything :-)

myList = [1, 70, 71, 72, 98, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 99]

# Create tuple list, show original and that list, then process.

tuples = reverseCombiner(myList)
print(f"Original: {myList}")
print(f"Tuples:   {tuples}\n")
for tuple in tuples:
    print(f"Would execute: worksheet.delete_rows({tuple[0]}, {tuple[1]})")
```

The output is:

```
Original: [1, 70, 71, 72, 98, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 99]
Tuples:   [(98, 2), (70, 3), (21, 5), (1, 1)]

Would execute: worksheet.delete_rows(98, 2)
Would execute: worksheet.delete_rows(70, 3)
Would execute: worksheet.delete_rows(21, 5)
Would execute: worksheet.delete_rows(1, 1)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks paxdiablo for your answer :D
Actually, the set value in my case is random number. Then I do reverse sort so the deletion process starts from the last row so it will not mess up the entire row.
Any additional suggestions?

Comment: @MuhammadDwiky: see the update. You can pre-process your arbitrary list to create a reverse-ordered `{row, count}` tuple list, then process that for the actual deletions. It can still degenerate into one row deletions if, for example, the input is `{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...}` but it will optimise the deltions as much as possible.

Comment: Woah that's awesome. It saves approximately 30 seconds:D
Big thanks my man!